# AngularJS Testing with Mocha and Sinon - Mocking Firebase Dependencies

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, mocking, mocha.js

I am trying to skip going to Firebase for my data in my tests, and return some simple results instead.  I do not want to test that the Firebase code works, but that my factories work in returning data.

I have the following factories:

```
// Get Firebase Reference
angular.module('MyApp').factory('FireBaseData', function(FIREBASE) {
    var FireBaseReference = new Firebase(FIREBASE.URL);  // FIREBASE.URL = xxx.firebaseio.com
    return FireBaseReference;
})

// Get the Firebase Array of Team Records
angular.module('MyApp').factory('AllTeams', ["FireBaseData",    "$firebaseArray",
    function(FireBaseData, $firebaseArray)  {
        return $firebaseArray(FireBaseData.child('Teams'));
    }
]);
```

I have created mocks that replace the individual functions, and my tests will use these.

```
'use strict';

var $MockFirebaseArray = function(ArrayWithData) {
    return ArrayWithData;
};

var $MockFirebaseObject = function(ObjectWithData) {
    return ObjectWithData;
};

var MockFirebaseData = function() {
    return {
        child: function(StringValue) {
            return "";
        }
    };
};
```

Tests with the mocks:

```
'use strict';

describe('Firebase Mocks', function() {
    var TestArray = [
        { 'aString': 'alpha', 'aNumber': 1, 'aBoolean': false   },
        { 'aString': 'bravo', 'aNumber': 2, 'aBoolean': true },
        { 'aString': 'charlie', 'aNumber': 3, 'aBoolean': true },
        { 'aString': 'delta', 'aNumber': 4, 'aBoolean': true },
        { 'aString': 'echo', 'aNumber': 5 }
    ];

    describe('MockFirebaseData', function() {
        var TestFirebase = MockFirebaseData();
        it('should return empty text ("") from FireBaseData', function() {
            assert.equal('', TestFirebase.child('SomeNode'));
        });
    });

    describe('$MockFirebaseArray', function() {
        it('should have the data array passed', function() {
            var TestData = $MockFirebaseArray(TestArray);
            assert.equal(TestArray.length, TestData.length);
        });
    });

    describe('$MockFirebaseObject', function() {
        it('should have the data object passed', function() {
            var TestData = $MockFirebaseObject(TestArray[0]);
            assert.equal(TestArray[0].length, TestData.length);
            assert.deepEqual(TestArray[0], TestData);
        });
    });
});
```

This shows that the Mocks are working to return data, which is what I want to stay away from actually accessing Firebase.  Now, when I try to use my factory in a test, I am getting errors.

Test the Factory:

```
describe('Teams Module', function() {
    beforeEach(module('MyApp'));        // Load My Application

    describe('AllTeams Array', function() {
        // Create Test Data
        var TeamData = [
            { "Key": 1, "Name":"Team 1", "Logo": "Team1.jpg" },
            { "Key": 3, "Name":"Team 3", "Logo": "Team3.jpg" },
            { "Key": 2, "Name":"Team 2", "Logo": "Team2.jpg" },
        ];

        beforeEach(function () {
            module(function($provide) {
                var MockData = MockFirebaseData();
                $provide.value('FireBaseData', MockData);
                $provide.value('$firebaseArray', $MockFirebaseArray(TeamData));
            });
        });

        it('can get an instance of AllTeams factory', inject(function(AllTeams) {
            assert.isDefined(AllTeams);
        }));
    });
});
```

Error returned:

```
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 7 0.0.0) 
Teams Module 
AllTeams Array 
can get an instance of AllTeams factory FAILED
TypeError: '[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]' is not a function (evaluating '$firebaseArray(FireBaseData.child('Teams'))')
    at app/Team.js:9
```

Comment: `$MockFirebaseArray` is returning an array. But then in `AllTeams`, you're trying to use it as a function.

Comment: @AnidMonsur I am trying to fix my factory to validate what it returns, since I believe the $firebaseArray() call normally returns array data.  I am trying to get the same thing for my factory.  Maybe my injection is faulty?  I want to validate I am getting back what I expect, so then I can use this same structured mock to work with the Controller that uses AllTeams to show the listings.

Comment: Perhaps you would be better off using [mockfirebase](https://github.com/katowulf/mockfirebase) to mock Firebase refs and leave AngularFire methods as they are.

Comment: I was trying to basically do that, without the need for the MockFirebase, as it looked to be more overhead than I needed, and not a quick drop in for testing.  Maybe I will check for more examples of this in actual use and try to use it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
$provide.value('$firebaseArray', $MockFirebaseArray(TeamData));
```

try this:

```
$provide.value('$firebaseArray', $MockFirebaseArray);
```

I believe this is what you were intending to do in the first place. When injected, your factory will then be able to call `$firebaseArray` as a function.

Comment: That seems to get past my current error. One more quick question would then be how to pass the array of data to get it back?  In my original line, sending the array gets it returned.  I would want to check now that my AllTeams returns the 3 records so I could process them.

Comment: It is still returning what you're passing in. But you're passing in an empty string, because that's what `MockData.child()` returns.

Comment: Thank you very much. That is what I was looking for.  My tests are now passing with good code coverage of my factories. Now I just need to figure out how to actually move the mockfirebase library in to allow me to test the rest of the Firebase add/remove factory functions.